# Api Security oauth: Does oauth2 make use of nonce and timestamp?

Tags: api, security, oauth, oauth-2.0

AWS uses HMAC authentication to makes its API secure. HMAC authentication uses nonce and timestamp to make api secure from replay attack.

I have read many documentations about the oauth2 protocol but have not found any article saying oauth2 make use of nonce and timestamp to prevent replay attack.

My question is if oauth2 is not using nonce and timestamp then how does it prevents replay attack?

Thanks,

Sanjay Salunkhe

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 2.0 relies on TLS for confidentiality, which means that the token/message cannot be intercepted by an attacker thus cannot be replayed. As the spec says in section 10.3, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.3:

> Access token credentials (as well as any confidential access token
> attributes) MUST be kept confidential in transit and storage, and
> only shared among the authorization server, the resource servers the
> access token is valid for, and the client to whom the access token is
> issued.  Access token credentials MUST only be transmitted using TLS
> as described in Section 1.6 with server authentication as defined by
> [RFC2818].